# DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, datatables

I have an error and it says "DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7". After that I went to inspect element and there's 1 error and says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Controller:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class section_controller extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->model('section_model','section');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('section_view');
}

public function ajax_list()
{
    $list = $this->section_model->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach($list as $section) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $section->sec_ID;
        $row[] = $section->secname;
        $row[] = $section->sec;

        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" 
        title="Edit" onclick="edit_section('."'".$section->sec_ID."'".')"><i 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>';

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->section->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->section->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    echo json_encode($output);
}

public function ajax_edit($sec_ID)
{
    $data = $this->section->get_by_id($sec_ID);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function ajax_add()
{
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
            'sec_ID' => $this->input->post('sec_ID'),
            'secname' => $this->input->post('secname'),
            'sec' => $this->input->post('sec'),
        );
    $insert = $this->section->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function ajax_update()
{
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
            'sec_ID' => $this->input->post('sec_ID'),
            'secname' => $this->input->post('secname'),
            'sec' => $this->input->post('sec'),
        );
    $this->section->update(array('sec_ID' => $this->input->post('sec_ID')), 
    $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

private function _validate()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['error_string'] = array();
    $data['inputerror'] = array();
    $data['status'] = TRUE;

    if($this->input->post('sec_ID') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'sec_ID';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'ID is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('secname') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'secname';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Section name is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('sec') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'dob';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Section is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($data['status'] === FALSE)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
}
}


?>
```

Model:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class section_model extends CI_Model{

var $table = 'section';
var $column_order = array('sec_ID','secname','sec',null);
var $column_search = array('secname','sec');
var $order = array('sec_ID'=>'desc');

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with 
             OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with 
            other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0'] 
    ['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}

function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function count_filtered()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function count_all()
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

public function get_by_id($sec_ID)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('sec_ID',$sec_ID);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}

public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function update($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

}

?>
```

And the View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sections</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo 
 base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo 
 base_url('assets/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')?>">
</head>
<body>
<br>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Sections</h1>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_section()"><i 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Section</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reload_table()"><i 
     class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Reload</button><br><br>
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
    cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Section ID</th>
                <th>Section Name</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Section ID</th>
                <th>Section Name</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')?>"> 
</script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"> 
</script>
<script src="<?php echo 
base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo 
base_url('assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var save_method;
    var table;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverside": true,
            "order": [],

            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('section_controller/ajax_list')? 
            >",
                "type": "POST"
            },

            "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets": [-1],
                "orderable": false,
            },
            ],
        });

        $("input").change(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });
        $("textarea").change(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });
        $("select").change(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            $(this).next().empty();
        });

        function add_section()
        {
            save_method = 'add';
            $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
            $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
            $('.modal-title').text('Add Section'); // Set Title to Bootstrap 
           modal title
        }

        function edit_section(id)
        {
            save_method = 'update';
            $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
            $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

            //Ajax Load data from ajax
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('section_controller/ajax_edit/')? 
           >/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $('[name="sec_ID"]').val(data.sec_ID);
                    $('[name="secname"]').val(data.secname);
                    $('[name="sec"]').val(data.sec);
                    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal 
               when complete loaded
                    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Section'); // Set title to 
              Bootstrap modal title

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error get data from ajax');
                }
            });
        }

        function reload_table()
        {
            table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax 
        }

        function save()
        {
            $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
            var url;

            if(save_method == 'add') {
                url = "<?php echo site_url('section_controller/ajax_add')?>";
            } else {
                url = "<?php echo site_url('section_controller/ajax_update')? 
              >";
            }

            // ajax adding data to database
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax 
               table
                    {
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                        reload_table();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < 
                  data.inputerror.length; i++) 
                        {



   $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has- 
   error'); //select parent twice to          select div form-group class and 
   add has-error class

    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
    //select span help-block class          set text error string
                        }
                    }
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error adding / updating data');
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

                }
            });
        }


    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
 label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Section Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Section 
   ID</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="sec_ID" placeholder="Section ID" 
   class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Section 
                        Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="secname" placeholder="Section Name" 
                            class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Section</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="sec" placeholder="Section" 
                       class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn 
       btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
       dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using codeigniter with datatables,jquery and bootstrap plugin.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and you'll likely see you aren't making your ajax request to the url you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

This is URLs' configuration problem . if your website enabled the Friendly URL or rewrite . you should see and check this configuration.